# play a MC from a button(should be simple)

Tags: flash

been a while since i used flash...

the minor problem im having is that, i have a button called " btninviz "
when this button is clicked, i want it to play a movieclip called " bannerRoll ".

the banner consists of a simple animation of images going back n forth etc...now,
for testing purposes, i want it so that on click, it goes and stops on the last frame (651)

ive created a function for it like so:

```
btninviz.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playBnnr);
function playBnnr(e:Event):void{
    bannerRoll.gotoAndStop(651);
    trace("working");   
}
```

when i click the button, i get this error which i dont know how to interpret:
***TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at jaro_fla::wholesect_2/playBnnr()[jaro_fla.wholesect_2::frame159:4]***

to make sure my function is working, i took out the bannerRoll part and just did a simple

```
btninviz.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playBnnr);
function playBnnr(e:Event):void{
    //bannerRoll.gotoAndStop(651);
    gotoAndPlay(1);
    trace("working");
}
```

and it works. so i know the function is working.
the MC DOES exist...matter of fact to make 100% sure, i took the button code and put it on the same frame where the MC exists and still nothing.

any ideas?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `bannerRoll` is failling which means it is ether at another location or under a different name.

As you just typed it's instance name make sure you are on the same frame as it. (Have you given it an instance name? Not just a movieclip name).

try `trace(bannerRoll)` if it traces undefined, you aren't accessing the movieclip correctly.

Comment: weird because i added the path as far as the MC nestings were concerned. but to no avail, i took the button and placed it inside the MC i was trying to affect and that was that...not what i wanted but as long as it works right lol. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your movie clip is on the same frame as your button.